# How to pass getResult object to Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Simple code :

```
/**
  * @Route("/search")
  */
    public function searchAction(Request $request) {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Bike::class);

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.brand >= :id')
        ->setParameter('id', '1')
        ->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getResult());
```

I tried

```
echo $result[0]['id'];
```

to save data to variables but it gives :

```
Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\Bike as array
```

Under

```
var_dump($result[0]);
```

I have some multidimensional array

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\Bike)[589]
  private 'id' => int 1
  private 'model' => string 'XXX' (length=9)
  private 'material' => string 'BBB' (length=6)
```

I want to pass this array or variables from array to *template.twig* .

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the basics of PHP, like accessing object properties

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks, PropertyAccessor helped me. :)

Comment: Why here `->setParameter('id', '1')` id is string?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev I changed code a bit so there are some verbal mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function searchAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $bike = $em->getRepository("NameOfYourBundle:Bike")->findAll();

    return $this->render('NameOfYourBundle:ForderName:nameOfTheView.html.twig', array('bike'=>$bike));
}
```

Now in your view :

```
{% for b in bike %}
    {% if b.id >= 1 %}
        // now put the names of attribs you need
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html)

you d find the solution, like this :

```
$this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
'variable_name' => 'variable_value',
));
```